# Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed

Tags: c#, error-handling, uri

I am trying to Construct a URI. But I am unable to handle bad URIs.

Is there any way we can handle bad URIs?

Code I am using:

```
if (reviews[e.Item.ItemIndex].URL.ToString().Contains("http:"))
{
      oURI = new Uri(reviews[e.Item.ItemIndex].URL.ToString());
}
else 
{
   oURI = new Uri("http://"+ reviews[e.Item.ItemIndex].URL.ToString());
}
```

`else` part gets error out for bad URIs.

Thank you!

Comment: If you use the Code Sample tag, it'll be much easier to read this

Comment: If you want to validate a supposed string is a valid hostname you might also find [`Uri.CheckHostName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.checkhostname?view=netframework-4.8) useful.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Call [`Uri.TryCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate.aspx):

```
string original = reviews[e.Item.ItemIndex].URL.ToString();
if (!original.StartsWith("http:"))
    original = "http://" + original;
Uri uri;
if (!Uri.TryCreate(original, UriKind.Absolute, out uri)) {
    //Bad bad bad!
}
```

Comment: Cool, I did not know it existed. I removed my post since your post seems to be the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

I had a space after "http:// " like http:// exampleServer/exampleservice.svc which had caused this error.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone, this could be the issue,
There was `Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed` for me on some urls and one some urls it was not coming.

I looked into the urls making issue, `they had '\' instead of '/' in urls`,

so in URI parsing it throws error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help some poor soul in the future. I just spent 5 hours bashing my head against a wall trying to figure out why SpecFlow was choking on this exact error. I couldn't find the smoking gun, but I am fairly certain for me it was the path name was too long, or potentially there was something bad in the path. When I moved the solution to smaller path name it worked. Here is the [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69813667/1248536) I posted about the specifics around the error I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar  error with nginx fastcgi-mono-server4. It turns out that webserver provided regex value for SERVER_NAME. So I have to fix it on the server by replacing `fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;` with `fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $host;`

Answer (score 0):

I got into a similar error  when trying to construct a URI object in C#.
For me the problem was the length.