# SpecFlowPlusRunnerAssemblyHook throwing exception Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed

Tags: .net, uri, specflow, configurationmanager

I am using SpecFlow with a .net 3.1 app. When I run/debug the tests I keep getting an error in some pretty deep dlls. It appears related to the ConfigurationManager.

> 2021-11-02T09:12:27.7102541-06:00:2021-11-02T09:12:27.7100969-06:00:Assembly resolving System.Private.Uri.resources, Version=4.0.6.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
> 2021-11-02T09:12:27.7366747-06:00:2021-11-02T09:12:27.7357023-06:00:OutOfProcessTestAssemblyExecutor: RunTest error: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize
> ---> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
> at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
> at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
> at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
> at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
> at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_ConfigPaths()
> at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(String configPath)
> at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
> at System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
> at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem..ctor()
> at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()

Another symptom is that the tests are skipped. I've debugged into the source and it appears to be a pathing issue, but I can't find any documentation about the System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem library.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the project to a smaller path appears to be the fix. It is possible there was something bad in the url `C:\Users\mynamee\source\repos\tfs\SomesProjMicroservices\TestAutomation\BRAN\AB.RSS.SomesProj.Microservices.TestAutomation\AB.RSS.Microservices.Common.Tests\Steps\SomereallyLongClasname`